# Miktex references not in order

Tags: bibliographies, sorting

I added the `\input{references}` line to the end of my Journal.tex file like so:

```
\input{references}
\end{document}
```

However, the references that are being outputted are not in order of citation. Rather, they are in the order that the citations are defined in the references.tex file. I did try adding the unsrt command as such

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99.}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

but no luck... I also tried deleting the aux files and stuff, but no cigar...

I am brand new to latex, so please help me out here! Thanks! I am not using the command line, but using TexnicCenter instead.

**EDIT:**

A snippet of my reference.tex class (sorted alphabetically).

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99.}

\bibitem{alexander87} Alexander, R. D., The Biology of Moral Systems, New York: Aldine de Gruyter (1987)
\bibitem{axelrod80a} Axelrod, R.: Effective choice in the iterated prisoner's dilemma, J. Confl. Resolut., vol. 24, pp. 3-25 (1980)
\bibitem{axelrod80b} Axelrod, R.: More effective choice in the prisoner's dilemma, J. Confl. Resolut., vol. 24, pp. 379-403 (1980)
\end{thebibliography}
```

What I want

```
..... no such cause [1].
```

what I get

```
..... no such cause [13].
```

FURTHER EDIT:

```
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}

\usepackage{mathptmx}         % selects Times Roman as basic font
\usepackage{helvet}           % selects Helvetica as sans-serif font
\usepackage{courier}          % selects Courier as typewriter font
\usepackage{type1cm}          % activate if the above 3 fonts are not available on your system
\usepackage{makeidx}          % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}         % standard LaTeX graphics tool when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}         % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} % places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{float}            % places the float image at precisely the location in the LaTeX code
\usepackage{verbatim}         % for multiline comments
\usepackage{subfigure}

\makeindex 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}   % for subsubsub sections (if any)
\begin{document}

\title*{Some random title.}

\author{Ockham}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

blah blah.........

\input{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Generating a sorted bibliography involves further steps. Do you use biblatex?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It's not clear here whether you are writing your bibliography by hand or using BibTeX, for example.

Comment: @Joseph thanks, i have edited my answer accordingly...

Comment: @OckhamsRazor No, that's not a MWE. We want something that starts `\documentclass` and ends `\end{document}`, and which is compilable.

Comment: @Joseph added more stuff.

Comment: @OckhamsRazor: We don't need *more* stuff, but all (and only) the *relevant* stuff. To keep it short: You `\input` a `references` file. Is this file called `references.tex` and, more important, does it contain a handmade `thebibliography` environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two strategies to get references sorted in citation order.

**1. Manual** You add the bibliography items in a file which starts as

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
```

and ends with

```
\end{thebibliography}
```

You have to add the items exactly in the order you want, in the `\bibitem{...}...` form you showed in your question. Then you say, where the bibliography should appear,

```
\input{references}
```

Alternatively, you can include the whole `thebibliography` environment in the document. The number  represents the maximum number of digits, so 99 is good for 10 to 99 items.

**2. Automatic** You prepare a `references.bib` file where you define your bibliography items in the following form

```
@book{alexander87,
  author={Alexander, R. D.},
  title{The Biology of Moral Systems},
  publisher={Aldine de Gruyter},
  address={New York},
  year={1987},
}
@article{axelrod80a,
  author={Axelrod, R.},
  title={Effective choice in the iterated prisoner's dilemma},
  journal={J. Confl. Resolut.},
  volume={24},
  year=1980,
  pages={3-25},
}
```

You prepare your manuscript and, where the bibliography should appear, you write

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}
```

A run of the external program BibTeX will read the `references.bib` file and extract the relevant information, producing a file with extension `.bbl` that LaTeX will later input. After running BibTeX a couple of runs of LaTeX are necessary.

How you run BibTeX depends on the TeX environment you use (editor, distribution, operating system).